# How can I check if a 3rd party static library for the iPhone SDK is compiled for Thumb?

Tags: ios, linker, xamarin.ios, thumb

I'm working with a development platform (monotouch) that does not allow me to link 3rd party libraries that are compiled for Thumb due to a bug in the apple linker. How can I determine if a library was compiled for thumb or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `otool -tv <LIBRARY>` on it and look for 2 byte instructions.

Here is an example showing thumb code: http://pastebin.com/4Kq52f9D 
Here is an example showing NON-thumb code: http://pastebin.com/137GJDR1